# how to check the content's length?

Tags: javascript

hi i am trying to create a shopping cart. What i want to do is click the 'done' button so i can cross-out the text.

```
    var shoppingList = document.getElementsByClassName("shoppingList");
    if (shoppingList.str.length > 0) {
        style.textDecorationLine = "line-through";
    }
        else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

is what I did on javascript file and

```
<head>
    <title>Javascript + DOM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
    <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    <ul>
        <li class="bold red" random="23"><a class="shoppingList" href="">Notebook</a><button id="done" type="button" >Done</button><button class="remove" type="button">Remove</button></li>
        <li><a class="shoppingList" href="">Jello</a><button id="done" type="button">Done</button><button class="remove" type="button">Remove</button></li>
        <li><a class="shoppingList" href="">Spinach</a><button id="done" type="button">Done</button><button class="remove" type="button">Remove</button></li>
        <li><a class="shoppingList" href="">Rice</a><button id="done" type="button">Done</button><button class="remove" type="button">Remove</button></li>
        <li><a class="shoppingList" href="">Birthday Cake</a><button id="done" type="button">Done</button><button class="remove" type="button">Remove</button></li>
        <li><a class="shoppingList" href="">Candles</a><button id="done" type="button">Done</button><button class="remove" type="button">Remove</button></li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

is what i put on my HTML file.
I think there should be something before `style.textDecorationLine = "line-through"`
but i'm not sure what that should be.

Comment: Hi Nayeong, welcome to SO. Your question still seems a bit vague. What do you mean with "the text"? Is the the text of the `.shoppingList` items? Just by looking at your code I can tell it will throw a lot of errors. Please attempt to fix your errors to get your code working and see what it does then. Also, hint, look into adding a class to elements. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The thing before the `style.textDecorationLine = "line-through"` is the variable containing the selected elemtent, e.g:

```
document.querySelector(".elementToCancel").style.textDecorationLine = "line-through";
```

OR

```
document.querySelector(".elementToCancel").style.textDecoration = "line-through";
```